What does Juan Diaz tell to Tsubasa in japanese in this scene?
In this scene from Captain Tsubasa in Spanish, Juan Diaz (argentine) says to Tsubasa, "how many cups do you have?"
Captain Tsubasa - Juan Diaz tells Tsubasa, How many cups do you have? 
In Latinamerica, we have a lot of football discussions between the different countries, because many of us like football a lot. We argentines are famous (or infamous) for telling people from other countries we consider to have a football level inferious to us, "how many cups do you have?" to end a discussion like saying, I'm not even going to argue with someone whose country football level isnt close to ours.
Now, I highly doubt japaneses know argentines in this level, it would be epic for us if they would, but I'm guessing this was made up by the spanish dub, since the spanish dubs of animes are mainly done by mexicans, and mexicans are the ones who tease us the most  about us (argentines) repeating this phrase all the time.
So I was wondering if in japanese, Juan Diaz actually told Tsubasa this, or it was made up for the spanish dub.
What does Juan Diaz tell to Tsubasa in japanese in this scene?

If you provided the Japanese audio this question would be a lot easier to answer.

@ocean eventually I might find it, but I dont know the episode. I just watched the original series (in spanish), this episode is from a sequel or movie I guess

It's either from the 2018 or the 2023 anime.
